# How do I successfully insert records from HTML form using php cleandata and sanitize functions

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have written a script to add records into my database with include functions for clean and sanitize the input data and my db connection file with query functions respectively but my problem is that once I submit the form No Closeable Alert message is displayed and record is not inserted into the table either.
Here is my script for record insertion

```
<?php
include('includes/functions.php');


//Require Database
include('includes/pdocon.php');

//instatiating our database objects
$db    = new Pdoconn;

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

//Collect Raw Data for Cleaning
$raw_firstName   = cleandata($_POST['fname']);
$raw_lastName    = cleandata($_POST['lname']);
$raw_username    = cleandata($_POST['username']);
$raw_email       = cleandata($_POST['email']);
$raw_pass        = cleandata($_POST['password']);
$raw_phone       = cleandata($_POST['phone']);
$raw_dateJoin    = cleandata($_POST['jdate']);
$raw_role        = cleandata($_POST['role']);
$raw_employId    = cleandata($_POST['employeeid']);

//Sanitize the Cleandate
$c_fname        = sanitizeValue($raw_firstName);
$c_lname        = sanitizeValue($raw_lastName);
$c_username     = sanitizeValue($raw_username);
$c_email        = validatemail($raw_email);
$c_password     = sanitizeValue($raw_pass);
$c_phone        = valint($raw_phone);
$c_jdate        = sanitizeValue($raw_dateJoin);
$c_role         = sanitizeValue($raw_role);
$c_employId     = sanitizeValue($raw_employId);

//Hash Password
$Hashed_Pass    = hashpassword($c_password);

//Query to Insert/Add Employees in employees Table
$db->query('INSERT INTO employees(id, firstName, lastName, username, email, password, employeeId, joiningDate, phone, role)VALUES(NULL, :fname, :lname, :username, :email, :password, :employeeId, :joiningDate, :phone, :role)');

//Bind Values to Query Parameters
$db->bindvalue(':fname', $c_fname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$db->bindvalue(':lname', $c_lname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$db->bindvalue(':username', $c_username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$db->bindvalue(':email', $c_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$db->bindvalue(':password', $Hashed_Pass, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$db->bindvalue(':employeeId', $c_employId, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$db->bindvalue(':joiningDate', $c_jdate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$db->bindvalue(':phone', $c_phone, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$db->bindvalue(':role', $c_role, PDO::PARAM_STR);

//Query to Check whether Staff Already Exist using Email
$db->query('SELECT * FROM employees WHERE email=:email');

//Bind Email Value
$db->bindvalue(':email', $c_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);

//fetch Row
$row            = $db->fetchSingle();

//check role
if($row){

    redirect('employees.php');
    //Closeable Alert Message
    keepmsg('<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
        <strong>Not Successful!</strong> Staff Already Exist, Pls Register another one.
        </div>');
}else{

//Run Query
$run_employee    = $db->execute();

if($run_employee){

    redirect('employees.php');
    //Closeable Alert Message
    keepmsg('<div class="alert alert-success text-center">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
        <strong>Success!</strong> Employee Registered Successfully.
        </div>');
}else{
    //Closeable Alert Message
    keepmsg('<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
        <strong>Not Successful!</strong> Employee Was Not Registered.
        </div>');
    }

}
```

}

?>

Comment: You never execute the `INSERT` statement

Comment: And you're not binding the values to the statement but to the PDO object

Comment: And there's not such thing as `PDO::fetchSingle` / PDOStatement::fetchSingle

Comment: this is where I am calling the execute function $run_employee    = $db->execute();

Comment: Oh, I missed that. But there's still the other issues where you always using the PDO connection object when you need to use the PDOStatement steatment

Comment: @ Alon Eitan, Tell me where I missed it and how it should be done. that is how I should bind the values to the statement because I did that through my pdocon.php function file

Comment: @AlonEitan that's probably some home-brewed wrapper for PDO

Comment: Without knowing details about `$db` implementation we can tell you nothing. Ans I suspect this wrapper is prone to many [common mistakes](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes). Hence I would strongly suggest to use vanilla PDO instead of this wrapper

Comment: @ Your Common Sense //Open Connection Method
 public function __construct(){

  $dsn  = "mysql:host=".$this->host. ";dbname=".$this->dbnm;

  $options   = array(

   PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT  => true,
   PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE   =>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION

  );

  now show me how